# constexpr specifier performance didn't meet my expectations in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, c++14, compiler-optimization

I have just learned that constexpr specifier function can run in compiling process, I tried to check the actual performance in VS 2017 with Debug x86 Mode, the result showed a tiny time difference between them. It still elapsed much time rather than "0". Did I do something wrong and could anyone help me,thanks a lot!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>

size_t r_fun(size_t n) noexcept
{
    if (n == 0) return 0;
    if (n == 1) return 1;
    return r_fun(n - 1) + r_fun(n - 2);
}

constexpr size_t c_fun(size_t n) noexcept
{
    if (n == 0) return 0;
    if (n == 1) return 1;
    return c_fun(n - 1) + c_fun(n - 2);
}


int main()
{
    clock_t start, finish;

    start = clock();
    auto r_x = r_fun(40);  
    finish = clock();
    std::cout <<"result:"<< r_x<< "\ttime:" << (double)(finish - start) << std::endl;

    start = clock();
    static const auto c_x = c_fun(40);
    finish = clock();
    std::cout << "result:" << c_x << "\ttime:" << (double)(finish - start) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `actual performance in VS 2017 with Debug x86 Mode,` dont check performance in debug mode.

Comment: `constexpr` does not exist to improve performance. So the fact that it doesn't improve performance in this case (even ignoring the debug build) is not a problem with the feature or its implementation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `constexpr` function requires **way too much** computation to do in a compiler, that's why the compiler chooses to delay it to runtime execution.

You can change this line:

```
static const auto c_x = c_fun(40);
```

to:

```
constexpr auto c_x = c_fun(40);
```

to see compiler's output. On clang, it tells me:

```
note: constexpr evaluation hit maximum step limit;
```

`c_x` is indeed a compile-time constant, but the compiler can't compute it due to implementation limitation. Note that your function has exponential complexity.

[Everything will be fine](https://godbolt.org/z/BonbIz) if you change 40 to some reasonable number, like 10:

```
constexpr auto c_x = c_fun(10);
```

Comment: Even at 40 a compiler may chew this up without issue. [g++ 8.1](https://godbolt.org/z/dnAer-) for example, clearly reduces down to the final answer. It all depends on the toolchain you're using and the limits it's imposing.

Comment: @WhozCraig For clang, this limitation can't be overridden by options, the `-fconstexpr-steps` option is of type `int`, this function requires `long` steps. https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/master/lib/Frontend/CompilerInvocation.cpp#L2464. But all in all, it's implementation dependent.